# I want to place text under other text, but I want them the same size!

Tags: text

```
$\underset{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}}{f: \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$
```

The text bellow is too small, I want it the same size as the text above.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but mathematical typesetting conventions indicate the use of `\colon` instead of the plain colon `:` in this setting. Plain `:` is a *relation* symbol, while `\colon` is a colon as punctuation. The spacing is different. (The `amsmath` package tweaks the spacing a bit more, actually.) The other issue is that the second arrow would normally be written `\mapsto` ($\mapsto$ … not sure why that does not render … as ↦). Oh, and `\rightarrow` has the shorter name `\to`.

Comment: (Uh, I forget that TeX is not rendered here, since TeX.SE is not MathJax-ified. I must've though I was on math.SE instead. So forget my subcomment about it not rendering.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\(
\begin{aligned}
f\colon\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}&\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
x&\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}
\end{aligned}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the first line aligned with the text?

Comment: Yes: `\begin{aligned}[t]`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way with your current code is to enforce `\displaystyle` in the lower part.

Also, `:` should be `\colon` and `\rightarrow` should be `\mapsto` as pointed out by @HaraldHanche-Olsen.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
%          V-----------V
$\underset{\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}}{f\colon \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \} \mapsto \mathbb{R}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: See my comment on the question.